# How do I make a password program in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, passwords

I am currently username and password was equivalent to one found in the code. This is what I have so far:

```
import os

#Must Access this to continue.
def main():
    while True:
        UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
        PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")

        if UserName == Bob and PassWord == rainbow123:
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            logged()

        else:
        print ("Password did not match!")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to ----")

main()
```

After I run the code, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\oysterDev\oysterDev.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Austin\Desktop\oysterDev\oysterDev.py", line 11, in main
    if UserName == Bob and PassWord == rainbow123:
NameError: name 'Bob' is not defined
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or where I could find some code that works like this for Python 3.4? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now your checking for a correct password and user with:

```
if UserName == Bob and PassWord == rainbow123:
```

Without quotes python expects that `bob` and `rainbow123` are defined variables. Since they're not defined it throws a `NameError`.

Just enclose those values in quotes:

```
import os
import time
#Must Access this to continue.
def main():
    while True:
        UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
        PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")

        if UserName == 'Bob' and PassWord == 'rainbow123':
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            logged()

        else:
            print ("Password did not match!")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to ----")

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out and you helped me almost as soon as I posted it! Thanks again! :D

Comment: Would the down voter care to explain?

Comment: I was gonna accept your answer last night, it just told me to wait 10 minutes. I then forgot, I accepted your answer now.